# Python with Hortonworks Sandbox or Cloudera Quickstart VM

Tags: python, hadoop

Can I use Python(v2/v3) for coding in Hortonworks Sandbox or Cloudera Quickstart VM  for hadoop?

I know we can use java but I am not so sure about python.

If yes, how do I set it up?

Comment: I know you can for Cloudera Quickstart.

Comment: thank you for your reply.
so how do i do it step by step?
can u provide any link/video for the above?
couldn't find anything related on google

Comment: This is from own experience. But generally Cloudera Quickstart is installed on a modern Linux which comes with Python by default. I am 100% certain that the 5.8 QuickStart VM for Oracle VirtualBox comes with RedHat and has Python installed. But even if this were not the case, you could always install it yourself.